# Is the Alternating group $A_5$ isomorphic to the external direct product $A_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, simple-groups

I have been thinking about this question for a while.

The Alternating group $A_5$ is isomorphic to the icosahedron group which has order 60. $A_5$ is a simple group which means the only normal subgroups are the trivial subgroup and itself.

The group defined by the external direct product $A_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$ is not simple but it does have order 60. Can we still define an Isomorphism from a simple group to a non simple group?

I might be over thinking this question but are all groups of order 60 isomorphic to each other?

Comment: No, it isn't true. simpleness is invariant over isomorphism

Comment: There are two isomorphism types of abelian groups of order $60$: $C_{60}$ and $C_2\times C_{30}$. The only nonabelian **simple** group of order $60$ is $A_5$. There are lots of nonabelian solvable groups of order $60$ (e.g., $A_4\times C_5$, $S_3\times C_{10}$). There are no nonabelian nilpotent groups of order $60$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without solvability/simplicity, one can use the center. The center of $A_5$ is the trivial group $\{1\}$ while the center of $A_4\times C_5$ is at least $C_5$.

Answer (score 1):

The group $A_4\times C_5$ is solvable, hence any homomorphic image of it is again solvable. Since $A_5$ is not solvable, there is no such isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not isomorphic. In fact, the group $A_5$ is simple, so it cannot be expressed as the internal direct product (or even semidirect product) of two nontrivial proper subgroups. It could, however, be a Zappa–Szép product, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sure, it's a Zappa-Szep product. If you take $H$ to be the stabilizer of a point to get a subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$ of order $12$, and $K$ to be a cyclic subgroup of order $5$ generated by a $5$-cycle (which is an even permutation), you get subgroups $H$ and $K$ with $|HK| = |H||K|/|H\cap K| = (12)(5)/1 = 60$, hence $HK=A_5$, so $A_5$ is  a Zappa-Szep product of $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact of being simple (and any other property that you can express without referring to the actual *name* of the elements or what they stand for in a particular case) is invariant under isomorphism.

As for your last question, God no, even if you consider only *abelian* groups, where the situation is [extremely simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification), there are more than one group of a given order $n$ as soon as $n$ is not a square-free number.